# IE randomly stops loading the necessary resources for a frontend

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, requirejs

I have a really strange problem with an AngularJS application using Internet Explorer (ver 11.0.9600.18697) as browser.

I am developing an application using AngularJS. The application runs perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE I'm experiencing the following problem.

What happens is that, when I start the application, **the startup stops because IE at a certain point randomly stops loading the necessary resources**, simply terminating some calls of js, i18n, css files.. (calls do not arrive at the server, simply IE blocks them, despite being the path all correct).

I have not understood the reasons of this behavior. What I know is that I use RequireJs for loading files (ver. 2.1.22), and that on Firefox and Chrome everything is loaded properly. Moreover, **if I start the application on IE keeping Fiddler open, then the application works very well on IE too**.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Here the network console:
[image]

Comment: and check your cache policy in the browser and in your server. maybe it will solve your issue.

Comment: Can anyone else or on another computer replicate same issue in IE? Also have you tried disabling all add-ons/plugins?

Comment: I have added missing information. And caching is completely disabled on my server.